# Display name change on PS3

Tags: ps3, psn, ps4

Can you change your online name (gamer tag is the Xbox equivalent) on PSN like you can on Xbox Live?

If so, how do you?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible at present although it is something Sony have talked about and acknowledged as a highly desired feature.

The following is an extract from article on [IGN](http://au.ign.com/articles/2014/11/14/heres-why-you-cant-change-your-psn-name-yet) regarding the issue quoting Sony Computer Entertainment America's President and CEO Shawn Layden:

> "The road map for feature extension is very long. It goes from here to
>   Hangzhou in China," Layden remarked when I asked about not only
>   changing one's PSN name, but about other oft-requested features like
>   deleting unwanted Trophies. "And all of those things are on there.
>   Yeah, we want to give you more control across your experience and your
>   profile and your presence on the network."
>
> "At the same time, as you'll understand, we don't want to make it so
>   that you can go in, grief a bunch of people in Far Cry, change your
>   avatar, change your username, go into CoD and grief everybody over
>   there. We want to stop that."
>
> When I asked if that issue specifically -- the risk of abuse -- is
>   what's holding up the feature being implemented, Layden answered in
>   the affirmative. Transparency in changing your name seems to be the
>   issue at hand.

Hopefully Sony can work out these issues soon.